# Does the number of bundles have great impact on performance?

Tags: symfony

I was reading this article on multiple apps for SF2 and there is one part about making leaner AppKernel. Since SF2 already caches most things when it boots up bundles, does creating a leaner AppKernel say for the API requests yield a big improvement in loading speed? What kind of possibilities we may have when loading a large number of bundles that I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, not really.

Because the "hardest" thing when loading a bundle is loading it's DI extension and running compiler passes. Fortunately, it's ran only when container gets compiled (cache warmup process).

This all is only true if you didn't *do anything stupid* (TM) in `boot()` method of your bundle. :)